# Groupby column and create lists for other columns, preserving order

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe which looks like this:

```
Id               timestamp           col1               col2
abc                789                0                  1
def                456                1                  0
abc                123                1                  0
def                321                0                  1
```

I want to group by or partition by ID column and then the lists for col1 and col2 should be created based on the order of timestamp.

```
Id               timestamp            col1             col2
abc              [123,789]           [1,0]             [0,1]
def              [321,456]           [0,1]             [1,0]
```

My approach:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

window_spec = W.partitionBy("id").orderBy('timestamp')
ranged_spec = window_spec.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

df1 = df.withColumn("col1", F.collect_list("reco").over(window_spec))\
  .withColumn("col2", F.collect_list("score").over(window_spec))\
df1.show()
```

But this is not returning list of col1 and col2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think the order can be reliably preserved using `groupBy` aggregations. So window functions seems to be the way to go.

Setup:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('abc', 789, 0, 1),
     ('def', 456, 1, 0),
     ('abc', 123, 1, 0),
     ('def', 321, 0, 1)],
    ['Id', 'timestamp', 'col1', 'col2'])
```

Script:

```py
w1 = W.partitionBy('Id').orderBy('timestamp')
w2 = W.partitionBy('Id').orderBy(F.desc('timestamp'))
df = df.select(
    'Id',
     *[F.collect_list(c).over(w1).alias(c) for c in df.columns if c != 'Id']
)
df = (df
    .withColumn('_rn', F.row_number().over(w2))
    .filter('_rn=1')
    .drop('_rn')
)
```

Result:

```py
df.show()
# +---+----------+------+------+
# | Id| timestamp|  col1|  col2|
# +---+----------+------+------+
# |abc|[123, 789]|[1, 0]|[0, 1]|
# |def|[321, 456]|[0, 1]|[1, 0]|
# +---+----------+------+------+
```

---

You were also very close to what you needed. I've played around and this seems to be working too:

```py
window_spec = W.partitionBy("Id").orderBy('timestamp')
ranged_spec = window_spec.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)

df1 = (df
    .withColumn("timestamp", F.collect_list("timestamp").over(ranged_spec))
    .withColumn("col1", F.collect_list("col1").over(ranged_spec))
    .withColumn("col2", F.collect_list("col2").over(ranged_spec))
).drop_duplicates()
df1.show()
```